# Is there a layout configuration qualifier for picture-in-picture (pip) mode layouts

Tags: android, android-layout, android-7.0-nougat, android-8.0-oreo, android-configchanges

I have implemented pip for my app.

I note that in the [Picture-in-picture support documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/picture-in-picture.html) it is suggested that

```
android:configChanges=
    "screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout|orientation"
```

is added to the manifest. This has the unwanted effect of preventing the activity lifecycle firing when the app goes into pip mode. and I want the activity - and therefore the layout - to be recreated.

Simple, I just don't use that line.

So now my activity is created and the layout inflated. Only Android is now inflating `<layout>-small.xml`. Now this is a better option than inflating the 'normal' layout but it's still far too too big a layout for pip mode. (small screens - at least 426dp x 320dp as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) - pip is MUCH smaller than that.

So my question is - is there an, as yet, undocumented layout configuration qualifier for pip size layouts, or do I have to tweak my small layout to make sure everything sits in the middle and so can be seen (not a very satisfactory solution).

---

**EDIT**

There **is** a qualifier `-pip`  i.e. `<layout>-pip.xml`, which I found by accident, that compiles without the error "invalid resource directory name". Good times.

BUT Android still inflates the `-small` layout when going into pip mode. Bad times

---

**UPDATE**

I have ended up implementing this by creating additional reduced layouts which I load in `onCreate`after checking `isInPictureInPictureMode()`. It's not my ideal solution but until I have a better one it is what it is.

Comment: Hey bro, didn't you faced any disturbing transition when activity is recreated while going to PIP mode? (Like PIP window vanishes for 1 sec and gets visible when activity recreation is done)

Comment: Yeah! I am facing such issues too